# Capture a function from parameter in NESTED function (closure function)

Tags: r, closures

Consider a code snippet as follow:

`f = function(y) function() y()`

> `f(version)()`
>
> Error in f(version)() : could not find function "y"

P.s. It seems that the closure mechanism is quite different from C# Lambda. (?)

**Q: How can I capture a function in the closure?**

--EDIT--

Scenario: Actually, I would like to write a function factory, and I don't want to add parameter to the nested function.

Like this:

```
theme_factory = function(theme_fun)
{
  function(device)
  {
    if (!is.onMac()) # Not Mac
    {
      (device == "RStudioGD") %?% theme_fun(): theme_fun(base_family="Heiti")
    }
    else
    {
      theme_fun(base_family="STHeiti")
    }
  }
}
```

And I defined two customized theme function for ggplot

```
theme_bw_rmd = theme_factory(theme_bw)

theme_grey_rmd = theme_factory(theme_grey)
```

Then I use them like:

```
function(device)
  ggplot(data) + geom_point() something like that + theme_bw_rmd(device)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is valid, try `f(installed.packages)()` for example. The only problem is there is no function `version`.

Comment: Try to use enviroment. See [link](http://www.lemnica.com/esotericR/Introducing-Closures/)

Comment: @flamenco Thanks. I've read your link above, but I still failed to figure out how to use environment under my circumstance. I've updated my question and provided a detailed scenario description, could you help tell me how should I modify the code? Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eval(func, envir = list(... captured parameters))` or `substitute(func, envir)` to eval the captured function in a specific environment.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is with passing parameter? What about something like this:

```
alwaysaddone <- function(f) function(...) f(...)+1
biggersum <- alwaysaddone(sum)
sum(1:3)
# 6
biggersum(1:3)
# 7
```

You can use `...` to "pass-through" any parameters you like.

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe my scenario clearly, and I've updated my question. Could you please help me figure out the solution? Thanks!

Comment: @Nathaniel It is unclear from your update what you the problem is. Are you saying the code doesn't work? Do you get an error? Do you expect a different result?